# DataMapper ORM simple OneToMany relationship

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-datamapper

This is the start of my relational model;

[image: ERD]

I don't to use DataMapper's redundant way of having a relational table for everything, but yet I can't seem to;

**Code**

```
<?php
$brand = new Brand(1);

var_dump($brand->themes->get());
```

**Brand**

```
    var $has_many = array(
        'themes' => array(
            'class' => 'theme',
            'join_table' => 'themes'
        )
    );
}
```

**Theme**

```
<?php

class Theme extends DataMapper {

    var $has_one = array(
        'brand' => array(
            'join_table' => 'brands',
        )
    );

}
```

This result in the brands.id field to fail;

```
SELECT `themes`.*
FROM (`themes`)
LEFT OUTER JOIN `brands` brands ON `themes`.`id` = `brands`.`theme_id`
WHERE `brands`.`brand_id` = 1 # <<< Wrong :(
```

I read the docs but it seems I'm reading too far fetched. I don't want to use the relational tables, unless it's a real ManyToMany relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your models:

**Brand**

```
var $has_many = array(
    'theme'
)
```

**Theme**

```
var $has_one = array(
    'brand'
)
```

Now you can easily get the info in your controllers. If you want to list the themes for a brand, use:

```
$_brand = new Brand;
$brand = $_obrand->get_by_id(1);
foreach($brand->themes AS $theme) {
    echo $theme->name;
}
```

Note: example above requires to autoload relations in the config, see [manual](http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/config.html):

```
$config['auto_populate_has_many'] = TRUE;
$config['auto_populate_has_one'] = TRUE;
```